# Check whether outbound port on server is open

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

I am trying to see whether my port `2195` (apples port) is open for outbound executions. I know that it is closed for inbound. I want to be able to check using php so I wrote this code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("example.co.uk", 2195, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Which returns the error:

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to example.co.uk:2195
>   (Connection refused) in /home3/.../public_html/.../example.php
>   on line 13 Connection refused (111)

But as I said I think this is due to the inbound port being closed.

So is there another way to test just the outbound?

Comment: Does `example.co.uk` allow you to access that port?

Comment: Yes for outgoing services

Comment: If it's not open to incoming connections then it won't reply and you won't be able to know.

Comment: are there any other methods?

Comment: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=5

Comment: You could maybe set up a service on the target which will accept incoming communications and reply back details pertaining to the port you wish to access. Other than that no there isn't really much you can do.